# Pine script coding - how to refer to an existing variable

Tags: pine-script

I'm still learning pine, but I'm hoping someone can help me with what I'm trying to do: I already have a variable that can return two different values: either 1 or -1. I want to create a new variable that'll only generate a signal when the first variable is 1. How can I do that. This is what I have:

````
fD = 0
sD = 0


fD := hlc3 > fastMA ? 1 : hlc3 < fastMA ? -1 : nz(fDirection[1], 1)
sD := hlc3 > slowMA ? 1 : hlc3 < slowMA ? -1 : nz(sDirection[1], 1)```

I want to create a new variable ```fDPOS``` when ```fD``` is equal to 1; essentially ignoring the -1 value. How can I do that in pine?
````

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your script as follows:

```
fD = sign(hlc3 - fastMA)
sD = sign(hlc3 - slowMA)
```

The `sign` function returns 1 when the argument is greater than 0 and -1 when lower than 0.

Then regarding your question I understood that you want to generate a new value once `fD = 1`, this can be done with:

```
fDPOS = change(fD) > 0 ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Thank you @alexgrover So by saying 

```fDPOS = change(fD) > 0 ? 1 : 0``` you're only taking in values/ setting fDPOS = 1 when fD is equal to greater than 0?

Comment: Question about the change function @alexgrover : looks like the sign function returns either 1 or -1 for fD and I want fDPOS value to be equal to fD value when fD is equal to 1. Doesn't change function take the difference between current and previous value? So if I use change and my previous value was 1 and current value is 1 wouldn't that set fDPOS = 1-1 = 0?

Comment: I understood "once", my mistake, so you can use instead `fDPOS = max(fD,0)`, here fDPOS will be equal to 1 when fD == 1, else 0.

Comment: Thank you @alexgrover ! Much appreciated!